# jsPDF wont read diffrent language letters using setLanguage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jspdf

Im a using jsPDF in angular 2, it seems like my html couldnt convert succesfully into pdf when its written in hebrew, other languages are fine, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with most of the PDF libraries and Hebrew.
You have to set custom font like **Arial**.

And then to set the RTL for text in Hebrew.